# How do I add INSERT permissions to my user in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I am using PHPMyAdmin in cPanel on a free web hosting site (2freehosting.com), and I have a database that I am trying to access using php. It says I don't have the permission. I then tried to run this SQL query in phpmyadmin:

```
GRANT INSERT ON DB.messages TO  USER@'IPADDR' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Username: `USER`

Database name: `DB`

Table name: `messages`

Password: `password`

Server IP: `IPADDR`

The error I get is:

> #1142 - GRANT command denied to user 'USER'@'localhost' for table 'messages'

I'm not sure how to get the permission to insert things into the database, because PHPMyAdmin is not showing a "privileges" tab on this hosting service. Does anyone know what to do about this?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: There's a page in cpanel for doing that, check this out https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/MySQL+Databases#MySQLDatabases-Modifyauser%27sprivileges

Comment: @rjdown How do I find that page? I'm not sure how to get there.

Comment: Home -> Databases, click on one and there should be a page to manage the database's users

Comment: @rjdown can I do this from PhpMyAdmin? Other than that, there's no button to manage database users.

Comment: Sounds like they have disabled the page on both cpanel and phpmyadmin, best contact their support team and ask.